# R : How to save first column from table as variable

Tags: r, variables, legend, scatter-plot

For the legend of my scatter plot in R I'd like to save the first column from my table as a variable.

Has anyone an idea how to do that?

I did try :

```
col[,1](a)->l
```

(a is the variable my table is saved as)

Comment: The type of question you're asking suggests you would profit more from taking a look at [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.pdf) than you would from getting an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

`l = a[,1]` should work. 
This will save the first column in data.frame 'a' to l

Without any data or examples of what you tried its hard to say.